# Can posedge in verilog be used only on clock?

Tags: verilog

Can a posedge be detected on variables that aren't a clock?

For example I have a reset button R, which should reset the machine to the starting state whenever it is pressed.

```
always @ (posedge clk, posedge R)
    if(R)
      reset_the_machine();
    else
      use_the_next_state();
```

Comment: This is a typical asynchronous active high reset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two questions in your question:

> can posegde in verilog be used only on clock?

The answer is no.

> Can a posedge be detected on variables that aren't a clock?

The anser is yes.

There are no *clocks* in verilog language. Every signal is equal. Edges could be detected in simulation on any variable. Detection of edges itself is a simulation artifact.

*Clock* is only a modern hardware artifact. A verilog program reflects hardware behavior and therefore it needs to program clocks in a specific hardware-related way. But this is just a programming trick.

As for your example, see dave-59's answer.

Answer (score 0):

The use of an *edge* on a signal like a set or reset is an artifact of the template pattern synthesis tools choose to represent asynchronous logic iin a single `always` block. If you didn't qualify `R` with `posedge` then the negative edge (`negedge`) of `R` would execute the `use_next_state()` branch. Thus simulation would be interpreting the release of reset as a `posedge` of clock.

When Verilog was first developed, the intent was to use separate `always` blocks for the synchronous and asynchronous behaviors using a procedural continuous assignment

```
always @(R)
  if (R)
     assign state = initial_state;
  else 
     deassign state;

always @(posedge clk)
    state <= next_state;
```

But today's synthesis tools no longer support this template probably because of confusion with the fully continuous `assign` statement.